# TypeError: flow_from_clientsecrets() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include_granted_scopes'

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

My route

```
@app.route('/oauth2callback')
    def oauth2callback():
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
            'client_secrets.json',
             scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
             redirect_uri=flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True),
             include_granted_scopes=True)
        if 'code' not in flask.request.args:
            auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
            return flask.redirect(auth_uri)
        else:
            auth_code = flask.request.args.get('code')
            credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
            flask.session['credentials'] = credential.to_json()
            return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('home'))
```

which when called gives the following exception

```
ERROR    2016-04-19 11:10:59,804 wsgi.py:279] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/mainsite/__init__.py", line 65, in oauth2callback
    include_granted_scopes=True)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/oauth2client/util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: flow_from_clientsecrets() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include_granted_scopes'
INFO     2016-04-19 11:10:59,881 module.py:787] default: "GET /oauth2callback HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least the current version of the oauth2client library doesn't support this `include_granted_scopes` argument: http://oauth2client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/source/oauth2client.client.html#oauth2client.client.flow_from_clientsecrets

You *might* be using some outdated code/documentation, others have reported the same issue before, for example: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-python-client/zQttW4WMUrg. I see the unsupported argument still present in [that referenced doc](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app#example).

As I gothered while researching the answer the argument seems to have been used for incremental authorisations. [That outdated referenced doc](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app#example) actually has an `Incremental authorization` section which shows:

> To avoid this complexity, you can include previously granted scopes in
>   your authorization requests. For example:
>
> ```
> flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(...)
> flow.params['include_granted_scopes'] = True
> ```